# Toggle between multiple images

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I have 4 images black, red, orange and green -  and the disabled version in gray.
What I want to achieve is that when I click on a disabled one, the other ones should turn gray/disabled and the one clicked should turn to his color image.

I tried following now this will get his child div and will do the toggle trick with the clicked image, but it won't disable the other ones. How can I disable all the other ones?

```js
$('.toggle').each(function() {
  var clickCounter = 0,
    firstEdit = false;
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    clickCounter++;
    if (clickCounter == 1 || firstEdit == true) {
      $(this).toggle();
      $(this).next('.toggled').toggle();

      clickCounter = 0;
      firstEdit = true;
    }
  });
});
$('.toggled').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggle();
  $(this).prev('.toggle').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle"><img class="" src="data/img/controller/orange.jpg"></div>
<div class="toggled"><img class="" src="data/img/controller/orange_disabled.jpg"></div>
<div class="toggle"><img class="" src="data/img/controller/red.jpg"></div>
<div class="toggled"><img class="" src="data/img/controller/red_disabled.jpg"></div>
<div class="toggle"><img class="" src="data/img/controller/black.jpg"></div>
<div class="toggled"><img class="" src="data/img/controller/black_disabled.jpg"></div>
<div class="toggle"><img class="" src="data/img/controller/green.jpg"></div>
<div class="toggled"><img class="" src="data/img/controller/green_disabled.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need loop through all images in onclick event handler and set proper class on each image. Also note, you could make images look grey with simple css filter, don't need create separate images

```js
const test = document.getElementById("test");
test.addEventListener("click", e =>
{
  for(let i = 0, children = test.children; i < children.length; i++)
  {
    children[i].classList.toggle("selected", children[i] === e.target);
  }
});
```

```css
.content > img:not(.selected)
{
  filter: saturate(0);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<span id="test" class="content">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/IlhDxQVsR17dwwER5xYZJej867KrdSx0K5eyRP2RFP4eQJMD2pi0ZGBhrMOcajBUP9M54lpmIr90JecPUFGPaRe3sDZ82RvHBSw1rw-YJvQs7J8K3g=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/aS2Up3osDMLTua1vXPTqnXko13KbIAmB0nQ44AP_IFTEt-VjUa6Tz2MC9jdH11bsZfjdiR8z4HbnxvhmmxSU1swKrtjc5PXreP6i=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dTH5_J82_TqXaLW_Hzq1rbMVqfzRWG9PkcKgHdjXphAy9M4MZF5Q7_cQZeM1kbqEYMysrBLlY4szACDZwIbP7Jm17BnGNjT0Tht8Qw=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
</span>
```

P.S.

> Please don't use bloatware jquery, save the planet.

Comment: @mplungjan there's more than one way to skin a cat ;) `for` loop might be longer and not as pretty, but it's the fastest loop available. Also, in this case pre-cache children has no benefit, it only makes the code static, which will not work if children added/removed dynamically.

Comment: @mplungjan with that solution I will not be able to have the same function for another image section: This statement will not be executed conditionally; only the first statement will be. The rest will execute unconditionally.sonarlint(javascript:S2681)

Comment: @nanchalantflow If I understand correctly you want to have more than one section with images: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75096590/295783

Comment: @vanowm until now there was no talk of dynamic - but I made a version that can handle that too

Comment: @mplungjan my point was, that your version had no benefit neither in performance nor in length of the code, other than the if statement which only could benefit if parent element clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Delegation for dynamic content

jQuery version

Change toggleClass to addClass to not toggle the clicked image

```js
$('#container').on('click', 'img', function() {
  $(this).siblings().each(function() { $(this).removeClass('selected') });
  $(this).toggleClass('selected')
});
```

```css
.content>img:not(.selected) {
  filter: saturate(0);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/IlhDxQVsR17dwwER5xYZJej867KrdSx0K5eyRP2RFP4eQJMD2pi0ZGBhrMOcajBUP9M54lpmIr90JecPUFGPaRe3sDZ82RvHBSw1rw-YJvQs7J8K3g=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/aS2Up3osDMLTua1vXPTqnXko13KbIAmB0nQ44AP_IFTEt-VjUa6Tz2MC9jdH11bsZfjdiR8z4HbnxvhmmxSU1swKrtjc5PXreP6i=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dTH5_J82_TqXaLW_Hzq1rbMVqfzRWG9PkcKgHdjXphAy9M4MZF5Q7_cQZeM1kbqEYMysrBLlY4szACDZwIbP7Jm17BnGNjT0Tht8Qw=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/IlhDxQVsR17dwwER5xYZJej867KrdSx0K5eyRP2RFP4eQJMD2pi0ZGBhrMOcajBUP9M54lpmIr90JecPUFGPaRe3sDZ82RvHBSw1rw-YJvQs7J8K3g=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/aS2Up3osDMLTua1vXPTqnXko13KbIAmB0nQ44AP_IFTEt-VjUa6Tz2MC9jdH11bsZfjdiR8z4HbnxvhmmxSU1swKrtjc5PXreP6i=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dTH5_J82_TqXaLW_Hzq1rbMVqfzRWG9PkcKgHdjXphAy9M4MZF5Q7_cQZeM1kbqEYMysrBLlY4szACDZwIbP7Jm17BnGNjT0Tht8Qw=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
  </div>
</div>
```

Vanilla - it does not toggle the clicked image

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

container.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches('img')) return;
  const images = tgt.closest('.content').querySelectorAll('img');
  images.forEach(img => img.classList.toggle('selected', img === tgt));
});
```

```css
.content>img:not(.selected) {
  filter: saturate(0);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/IlhDxQVsR17dwwER5xYZJej867KrdSx0K5eyRP2RFP4eQJMD2pi0ZGBhrMOcajBUP9M54lpmIr90JecPUFGPaRe3sDZ82RvHBSw1rw-YJvQs7J8K3g=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/aS2Up3osDMLTua1vXPTqnXko13KbIAmB0nQ44AP_IFTEt-VjUa6Tz2MC9jdH11bsZfjdiR8z4HbnxvhmmxSU1swKrtjc5PXreP6i=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dTH5_J82_TqXaLW_Hzq1rbMVqfzRWG9PkcKgHdjXphAy9M4MZF5Q7_cQZeM1kbqEYMysrBLlY4szACDZwIbP7Jm17BnGNjT0Tht8Qw=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/IlhDxQVsR17dwwER5xYZJej867KrdSx0K5eyRP2RFP4eQJMD2pi0ZGBhrMOcajBUP9M54lpmIr90JecPUFGPaRe3sDZ82RvHBSw1rw-YJvQs7J8K3g=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/aS2Up3osDMLTua1vXPTqnXko13KbIAmB0nQ44AP_IFTEt-VjUa6Tz2MC9jdH11bsZfjdiR8z4HbnxvhmmxSU1swKrtjc5PXreP6i=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dTH5_J82_TqXaLW_Hzq1rbMVqfzRWG9PkcKgHdjXphAy9M4MZF5Q7_cQZeM1kbqEYMysrBLlY4szACDZwIbP7Jm17BnGNjT0Tht8Qw=w102-h68-n-l50-sg-rj">
  </div>
</div>
```